# Queuing Scripty2 animations

Tags: javascript, animation, prototypejs, scriptaculous

The docs say that adding `position: end` queues animations one after 
the other. Right?

But then something like this doesn’t work:

```
$('box').morph('height:100px', {duration:3, position:'end'});
$('box').morph('background-color:red', {duration:3, position:'end'});
$('box2').morph('background-color:pink', {duration:3, position:'end'});
```

→ http://jsfiddle.net/kf8Ys/

The second box turns pink when it’s supposed to wait for the first box to turn 
red. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply chain morphs like this:

```
$('box').morph('height:100px', {duration:3}).morph('background:#ff0000', {duration:3});
```

Also, you have to write 'background:#ff0000' and put the background-color in the style attribute of your boxes, otherwise you will never be able to change the BG via js.

Here's your edited exapmle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vhy8e/

Update:
If you want to make #box2 to turn red after the first 2 morphs finished:
http://jsfiddle.net/W5w6S/

Comment: I was hoping not to use `after` because if I wanted a _long_ series of sequential events, then it would become unmanageable (a function in a function in a function … [whoaaa](http://www.instantinception.com/).)